# How to apply the style you want for one input block using Attribute selector?

Tags: html, css, input, selector

I create a few blocks and I need to make one of them with a special wide, as I solve this problem?
[image]

there is my Html code

```
<section id="sec">
  <input type="text" name="myname1" />
  <input type="text" name="myname2" />
  <input type="text" name="myname3" />
</section>
```

and Css code

```
#sec input {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 2px 0 27px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[name=myname2] {
  width: 150px;
}
```

**See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex9qh/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple to resolve. Selector `#sec input` is more important than `input[name=myname2]` because it's descendant selector, and CSS specify that descendants are more important than one–element selectors. In order to make your `input[name=myname2]` works properly just change it to `#sec input[name=myname2]`.

Then, because `#sec input[name=myname2]` is descendant and more specific it overwrites `#sec input`.

Cheers